# display detail information in group header

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to take all the first name records in one group and display them in the group header. However I am having a problem in resetting the variables properly. 
So far I am using

```
@FirstName //this formula is in the details section
global StringVar FirstName; 
If previous ({Customer.FirstName})<> ({Customer.FirstName}) Then FirstName:="";
FirstName := FirstName + {customer.FirstName};
```

and then..

```
@CompleteFirstName //this formula is in the groupheader 
global StringVar FirstName; 
FirstName;
```

The problem is that the group headers are showing in the wrong sections, 
The first group header is empty and then the second group header shows the first's information

Comment: Your problem arises from the fact that formulas (and global variables' values, by extension) are evaluated from top to bottom on the page. For example, the first group header is blank because the variable `FirstName` has not been assigned ANY value yet since it precedes any details section, so no instance of `{@FirstName}` has been evaluated at that point.

Comment: Why do you need the firstname formula on  the Details section. Why cant you just have it on the Group Header. Infact I think you can do it all using the just one formula CompleteFirstName placed on the header with the Previous condition check. This way you can build the string on every group. This also addresses the problem Ryan suggested. This is assuming Customer.FirstName is a group.

Comment: @amazing The report is grouped by another field, and I want the complete list of firstNames on the group header

Comment: @Ryan Is there any other way to accomplish this??

Comment: @Dmandy The easiest way is to just change the layout of the report so that your group information appears in the group's footer instead. If that isn't an option you can try to use a SQL Expression to concatenate all of the first names for each group; essentially you'd be writing a subquery to do all of the heavy lifting for you. Similarly, you could create a subreport to display just this one piece of data.

Comment: What type of SQL expression?

Comment: @Dmandy There is only one type, but it has to be valid SQL syntax for the kind of database you're using. If you've never used them before I would suggest Googling for a tutorial as they can sometimes be difficult to get working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Write formula like this

```
StringVar FirstName; 
If previous ({Customer.FirstName})<> ({Customer.FirstName} then Then FirstName:="";
FirstName := FirstName + {customer.FirstName};
```

And put it in your group footer. Problem solved. Sorry for misunderstood first time.

Comment: This will also not work, unfortunately. This will only evaluate once per group instead of for every record and you'd be missing out on many names as a result.

Comment: And I need it in my group header NOT footer

Comment: If you suppress group header and detail section and only showing group footer then the footer can act like group header. It's easier for CR to work that way without making big formulas. I tested this solution on my created data and it worked for me, so don't understand where is problem?